# Português medieval: Quais são estes grafemas, e que sons têm?

Tags: português-europeu, ortografia

Comecei a ler "Décadas da Asia" de João de Barros, publicado eom 1552 ([disponível aqui](https://archive.org/details/asia00barr/page/n9/mode/2up)).

Grande parte do texto é surpreendentemente legível para um texto de 500 anos, porém a ortografia era claramente diferente. Alguns grafemas eu já conhecia por serem similares ao inglês antigo, como o S longo (ſ):

[image: ſignificativa] (significativa)

ou esta forma de R onde a linha vertical não é escrita:

[image: brevidáde] (brevidade)

Porém também encontrei estes grafemas que não consegui identificar:

[image: corrompe e(?) altera] (corrompe (e)? altera, talvez um &?)

[image] (?).

Então busco qualquer ajuda neste quesito para estes e outros grafemas antigos. Imagino que referências para ajudar leitores modernos dessas obras antigas provavelmente existem, mas não encontrei nada em minhas pesquisas online, então qualquer ajuda neste quesito também é bem-vinda.

Comment: 1551 não é medieval. Já era o Renascimento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O primeiro é uma nota tironiana que significa "e" (a conjunção), "⁊". Portanto, diz "corrompe e altera".

O segundo é apenas um A maiúsculo e ornado, portanto diz "Asia".

Recomendo um livro chamado "Filologia, história e língua: olhares sobre o português medieval".

EDIÇÃO: mas aproveito para lembrar que no século XVI não se considera mais português medieval, mas creio que o livro será útil de qualquer forma!

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: E os primeiros dois?

Comment: O primeiro, como disse o Bruno, é um S-longo, e o segundo é chamado R-rotunda, usado antes de letras redondas.